# Compare 2 excel file with a reference column using python

Tags: python, excel, validation

I want to compare 2 excel files (file1 & file2) with a unique column as reference (eg: Emp ID). Based on this unique ID, compare every row data from file1 against the corresponding row data in file2 and create an output file with all the columns from file1 and mismatching row data (with mismatching columns only) from file2 in format shown in image.

This current script works for 2 files identical in shape, order and format of data. Need help to validate based on reference column.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ej2Ty.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just use spreadsheet compare tool, if this is one time job,

it's a built-in tool in windows

```
Spreadsheet Compare
```

Comment: this can help to compare 2 versions of files. But I want to compare 2 files with similar and different column data. We need to compare only the selected columns with a reference column like we compare data join statements.

Comment: but your example image shows like both files are similar